# Button value changes via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Sorry but I'm quite a noob if it comes to Javascript with HTML.
I'm trying to make a button that will change the value of it when a multiple checkboxes are checked.

Example: 
If one checkbox is checked    = Button: Delete 1 row
If two checkboxes are checked = Button: Delete 2 rows
etc.

And I want this to happen automaticly when I check all checkboxes. The only problem is that I don't know how to call the value of it in a button.

JS:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function() {
        $("input[type=submit]").val("Delete "+$('input:checkbox:checked').length+" rows"); 
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="Verwijder" />
```

The server-side of this(PHP) does work(deleting the rows).
Thank you for helping and your time!

Comment: `value="checked()"` really ??

Comment: I first had onclick, the only thing was that onclick is after and what I want is the value.

Comment: I should note that you can't name a function `checked()` as it is a boolean value. Consider naming it `isChecked()`

Answer (score 2):

you can change the value of a button by using this function

```
function change(val)
{
document.getElementById(12345).value=val;
}
```

while creating button give an id to it like `id="12345"`.....

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this listening to the click event of the checkboxes and applying the value by getting the length of `$('input:checkbox:checked')`

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/Ls8sp/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function() {
   $("input[type=submit]").val("Delete "+$('input:checkbox:checked').length+" rows"); 
});
```

Comment: I've tried to do this but nothing will change. Thank you for giving a JS Fiddle but nothing won't work. I've changed the orginal post to see what I now have. Thank you for helping so far.

Comment: @RezaM Are you sure your button has the input type of 'submit'? Are you using a button or an input?

Comment: A button, <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="Verwijder" />

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("click","input[type=checkbox]",function()
{
   $("input[type=submit]").val("Delete "+$('input:checkbox:checked').length+" rows"); 
});
```

Comment: And what needs to be the value of the input button? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Spedwards - no problem ... I changed it ... but why you post the same solution ??? I'm getting angry

Comment: @pooler I just posted my solution. It was a revision of yours.

Comment: I think .. $(document).on() .. is not so big problem as you meantioned  .. you just give me vote down and "steal my solution"

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can change the value of the element within your script.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')===true){
        i++;
    }
    else{
        i--;
    }
    $('input[type="submit"]').val("Delete "+i);
});
```

Comment: And what needs to be the value of the input button? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Whatever you want. It will be changed afterwards using `.val()`. Use a string rather than a function return.

Comment: You shouldn't use `attr()` as it will get the value it loaded as. Instead, use `prop()`.

See prop() vs attr(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @Spedwards oh ok. Never seen that before.

Comment: He won't change it, check the orginal post for the update. Thanks for helping so far.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this

## HTML

```
<form>
    <ul>    
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item one</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item two</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item three</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item four</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item five</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item six</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item seven</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item eight</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item nine</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />item ten</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete (0)" />
</form>
```

## jQuery

```
var getChecked = function($form) {
    return $form.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
};

$form = $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getChecked($form).each(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});

$form.find('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
    $form.find('input[type="submit"]').val('Delete (' + getChecked($form).length + ')');
});
```

**see live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtgCp/)**